# How sparkpost edits email "to" and "cc" header?

Tags: email, smtp, amazon-ses, email-client, sparkpost

In sparkpost, if I was to send emails to "person.1@email.com", "person.2@email.com" & "person.3@email.com" & along with that have cc'ed email "cc.person@email.com".

```
{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "address": {
        "email": "person.1@email.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "address": {
        "email": "person.2@email.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "address": {
        "email": "person.3@email.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "address": {
        "email": "cc.1@email.com",
        "header_to": "person.1@email.com;person.2@email.com;person.3@email.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "content": {
    "from": "you@fromyou.com",
    "headers": {
      "CC": "cc.1@email.com"
    },
    "subject": "To and CC",
    "text": "This mail was sent to many while CCing cc.1@email.com."
  }
}
```

Here cc would only get 1 email, with all "to" addresses in email's to header.
All other "to" emails would also get 1 email, where each recepient is only able to see 2 emails : his own & the cc email.
My question is how do they do this? I have to replicate this to Amazon Ses raw email. I tried sending emails indiviually, but cc is getting `n + 1` emails as there are `n` "to" & 1 of his own.

I tried to send email individually in Amazon ses raw email but cc gets `n + 1` emails as he has been cc'ed in those `n` "to" emails.

Comment: @tripleee Cc: copy email have all `To: ` recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers only matter for display purposes; what is actually being sent is determined by the SMTP envelope. There is no way to have individualized headers in each message other than by sending individualized messages. Probably behind the scenes, they split up the message into multiples after generating the Cc: copy.

In some more detail,

- Generate a message with all the `To:` recipients in the headers, but only send it to the `Cc:` recipient
- Then, for each `To:` recipient, generate and send a new message only to them

There are many questions about the difference between headers and envelope information. In very brief, SMTP lets you specify the sender with `MAIL FROM:<me@example.org>` and each recipient with `RCPT TO:<victim@example.net>`; and then, you supply the message in the `DATA` transaction, including all the headers. (The headers will be updated by reach handling MTA; on delivery, the final MTA will usually put the envelope sender in `Return-Path:`, and optionally the final local recipient in `Delivered-To:`.)

Comment: Thanks man. You really saved the day. I tried your approach and it worked for me. You were right, headers only matter for display purpose. For each `to` email I sent separate email with `cc` header and in Amazon Ses's raw email api, for `Destinations` argument I passed a single email only. And it did worked.

Comment: I will update my question to have the approach shown by you in form of code later this day so it would help others also.

Comment: No, don't; feel free to post an _answer_ of your own if you think that will be useful; but your question should remain strictly a question.